# Add one UIwebView to UITableViewCell of two UITableViews

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two tableviews, each tableview has only one cell to contain  and now I want to add one UIWebView to this two tableviews' cell

```
- (void)loadView
{
    interestView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:_webViewFrame];
    interestView.delegate = self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }
        //interestView is UIWebView
        if (tableView == interestTableView) {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:interestView];
        }else if (tableView == headerTableView) {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:interestView];
        }
}
```

but this is not work, both table cell not shows the UIWebView. Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean that your both tableView's have only 1 cell each and in that cell you want to add a UIWebView?

Comment: it is very weird situation... what is the `interestView`? how is was inited?

Comment: @NayanChauhan yes, right, and the UIWebView is the same one

Comment: what is current value of the `_webViewFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the frame of your `UIWebView` before you add it as a subview of the `UITableViewCell`.

```
interestView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,cell.contentView.frame.size.width,cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
```

Then when you add it you should be able to see it?

Comment: If that hasn't worked try @SorinAntohi answer. That would be my next step

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom table view cell that has a uiwebview as a subview and then add it to your table views instead of the default UITableViewCell that you are using. You will not need to add subviews from code or update the frames if you define your custom cell in a xib.